# RecyclerView items not getting removed

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a RecyclerView to display a list of cards. On pressing a certain button on a card, the item associated with it is supposed to be removed from the database as well as the RecyclerView, therefore displaying a freshly updated RecyclerView with the remaining items.

Now the issue is that when I remove an item by pressing the button, the Firebase ValueListener is triggered and a fresh RecyclerView is to be generated, but instead, each of the remaining items is duplicated. This gives me a RecyclerView which has two of each item.

**The ValueEventListener code block**

```
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            discoverPeopleList = new ArrayList<>();
            discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter = new DiscoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), discoverPeopleList);
            discoverPeople.setAdapter(discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter);

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                final java.lang.String
                        key = snapshot.getKey();
                DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("users").child(key).child("followers");
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            boolean isBeingFollowed = false;
                            for (DataSnapshot ss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                if (ss.getKey().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                                    isBeingFollowed = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!isBeingFollowed && !key.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                                Log.v("Add", "One key added");
                                discoverPeopleList.add(key);
                                discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }else if (!key.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                            Log.v("Add", "One key added");
                            discoverPeopleList.add(key);
                            discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            discoverPeopleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            discoverSessionsProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**The OnClickListener code block in the adapter class(This is where the item is removed from the database)**

```
holder.followBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.followBtn.getText().equals("follow")){
                DatabaseReference followers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userKey).child("followers");
                followers.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notificationRequests").child("username").setValue(userKey);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notificationRequests").child("message").setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + " followed you");

                DatabaseReference following = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("following");
                following.child(userKey).setValue(userKey);

                holder.followBtn.setText("following");
            }else{
                DatabaseReference followers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userKey).child("followers");
                followers.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();

                DatabaseReference following = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("following");
                following.child(userKey).removeValue();
                holder.followBtn.setText("follow");
            }
        }
    });
```

**The Layout XML**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#303030"
tools:context="com.veloxima.sporthub.LiveDiscover">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/discover_people_recyclerVIew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit:** I have confirmed that the ArrayList does indeed get cleared. The RecyclerView, on the other hand, is still messing up.

Answer (score 1):

When anything changes under `usersRef`, you'll get a complete new snapshot of the data under that location. So your code ends up adding all users (except for the one that was removed) to the `discoverPeopleList` again.

To stop this from happening, you'll need to clear `discoverPeopleList` before adding the new data:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
        boolean isBeingFollowed = false;
        discoverPeopleList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if (ss.getKey().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                isBeingFollowed = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isBeingFollowed && !key.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
            Log.v("Add", "One key added");
            discoverPeopleList.add(key);
            discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }else if (!key.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
        Log.v("Add", "One key added");
        discoverPeopleList.add(key);
        discoverPeopleRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This will work, but result in a complete redraw of the RecyclerView. To allow you to more granularly update the data, you should use `addChildEventListener`. This listener allows you to respond to individual child events, such as `onChildAdded` for adding users (including all the initial users) and `onChildRemoved` for removing them.

To see an example of such an adapter, see this code in the FirebaseUI library: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: this would clear the recyclerview every time the loop moves on to the next object, therefore not ending up with any items at all.

Comment: Ah right, I missed the nesting. And you're already creating a new `discoverPeopleList ` list in the outer `onDataChange`. I'm not sure what's going on there then, but I'd still recommend listening for child events for the `usersRef`.

Comment: Actually tell you what, It was working fine before I added another RecyclerAdapter in the same Fragment. Should I edit my question and put the whole class in there?

Comment: Don't just add more code from your app, that will just make it harder to see what's going on. Reproduce the problem with the minimal amount of code possible and share that. See [How to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok so I removed all the additional code and tried running it, the problem is still there. This code block is all there is to it. I hope someone can point out what the issue is.